# Cut off beginning of a large file in PHP

Tags: php, file-io

I would like to cut off the beginning of a large file in PHP. Use of `file_get_contents()` is not possible due to memory restrictions.

What is the best way to delete the first `$n` characters from a file?

If it is possible to do it without creating a second file, I would prefer that solution.

**Update** After the file has been modified, it will be used by other scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have enough memory to buffer the entire file, you'll need to create two files (at least temporarily) regardless of your solution.

Look into [`fseek()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php), which allows you to go to a particular byte position within a file.

```
// Open the file
$filename = 'somefile.dat';
$file = fopen($filename, 'r');

// Skip the first 1 KB
fseek($file, 1024);

// Your processing goes here...

// Close the file
fclose($file);
```

In your case, you could open the original file for reading and the temp file for writing concurrently. Seek the original file. Loop over the original file, reading a small chunk and writing it to temp. Then rename temp to have the same name as original.